# Get keys from object which uses an interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can I get an objects actual keys when I'm using an interface to describe the object?

Example below

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}
interface IAddress {
    [key: string]: IPerson;
}

const personInAddressObj: IAddress= {
    someAddress1: {
        name: 'John',
    },
    someAddress2: {
        name: 'Jacob',
    }
} as const

type Keys = keyof typeof personInAddressObj;
```

Id want the type Keys to have the values "someAddress1 | someAddress2".  If I take the interface out of "personInAddressObj", I can get the keys. However, when the interface is used, I can't get the actual keys out of the object.

Comment: If you mean using those keys as type (that what's you write), then you can't. Typescript compiles on static info, hence you can't have runtime data at compile-time. However, if the keys are used for runtime stuffs, you can leverage the `Object.keys(personInAddressObj)`, which gets you the keys as array of strings. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31062) for the corresponding open TypeScript feature request.

Comment: @MarioVernari Objects declared with a const assertion (`as const`) *are* compile-time information.

Comment: "*If I take the interface out of `personInAddressObj`, I can get the keys.*" - so, why not do that? There's no point in using `as const` if you did assign to a variable declared as `IAddress`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that's new to me. Many thanks for pointing me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31062) for this specific use case.

For your specific example, I think you can use the new (since TypeScript 4.9) [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator) operator to have both a `const` assertion and type checking:

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}

interface IAddress {
    [key: string]: IPerson;
}

const personInAddressObj = {
    someAddress1: {
        name: 'John'
    },
    someAddress2: {
        name: 'Jacob'
    }
} as const satisfies IAddress;

type Keys = keyof typeof personInAddressObj;
// ↑ inferred as "someAddress1" | "someAddress2"
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAsAFDLnIhwC2EAXMlmFKAOYDcpAvqaaJLEQpUAQQAmYqBCxZCpCsgDaAawgBPBkxYhWAXQYZseTiR4lSCPE2QAHIyFQhxk6VgDyAIwBWyALxyyClxaZykZAEYGYkCFcipaBgByACkcAAsQRPkKLgAabPJgiFDXACYogtj4+mQUxBwPLJjkMy5kOFlLEGssODBgLBhgaTQSmRNSMDU7ZABpdVl-VTUcGGQpu1Xbe0cx928TAHpD5EBEwmRQGGgpMXbZACIivfD75AAfZEecEIkwrFL7kA)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks for helping out!