# Missing Autocomplete for Key/Value Object Types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a simple key-value object type, but after initializing an object with this type, I lost VSCode autocompletion.

```
type Custom = {
    [key: string]: string
}

const test: Custom = {
    a1: 'foo',
    b1: 'bar',
    c1: 'baz',
}
```

Without type assignment, after typing `test.`, (`a1, b1, c1`) automatically pop out. But after giving a type, `test.` shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a value to an untyped variable in TypeScript, the type of the variable is [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) based on the expression on the right side of the assignment.

So, for a variable `test` declared as follows:

```
const test = {
    a1: 'foo',
    b1: 'bar',
    c1: 'baz',
}
```

The type of `test` is now:

```
type T = typeof test; // type T = { a1: string; b1: string; c1: string; }
```

So it becomes illegal, for example, to add extra properties to `test`:

```
test.d1 = 'qux'; // Property 'd1' does not exist
                 // on type '{ a1: string; b1: string; c1: string; }'
```

On the other hand, if you set the type of `test` to `Custom`, this type narrowing does not take place:

```
type Custom = {
    [key: string]: string
}

const test: Custom = {
    a1: 'foo',
    b1: 'bar',
    c1: 'baz',
}

type T = typeof test; // type T = { [key: string]: string; }

test.d1 = 'qux'; // OK
```

In short, you lose autocompletion because the `Custom` type is wider than what you have defined in the object literal, and TypeScript does not start guessing which properties you might have added to, or removed from, the object in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Is there a way to get auto-completion for the Custom type?

Comment: You can use a `const` assertion together with the `satisfies` keyword: `cont test = { /* ... */ } as const satisfies Custom;` See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74740208/3558960).